# Existence of automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^n$ taking a given set of points to another given set of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given two sets $X= \{x_1, x_2. ...x_d\}$ and $Y= \{y_1, y_2, ... y_d\}$ of $d$ points in linearly general position in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Further assume that the images of $X$ and $Y$ under a projection map $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \to \mathbb{P}^1$  are same. Then my question is does there exist an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^n$ which take $X$ to $Y$ ? If $d \le n+2$, then it is always exist (with out the hypothesis on the image of a projection map ).

Comment: Do you mean just one projection? Then certainly not.

Comment: what should be appropriate hypothesis ? do we need for all projection ? or some weaker hypothesis may work ?

Comment: and why it is not certainly true ?

Comment: Take affine coordinates so that your projection is given by the last coordinate. You can impose the last coordinate of $x_i$ equal to that of $y_i$, and the other coordinates totally arbitrary.